# jQuery - TypeError: "".match is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, delegates

```
(function( $ ) {

    $(function() {

        $( '.AddRow' ).delegate( 'click', function() {
            var $this = $( this ),
                $tbody = $this.parents( '.tbody' );
            $tbody.find( 'td:nth-child(-2)' ).css( 'background', 'red' );
        });

    });

})( jQuery );
```

I'm getting the following error :

```
Timestamp: 07/08/2013 21:02:49
Error: TypeError: "".match is not a function
Source File: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Wamp/www/kbd-creator/v5/jquery-1.10.2.min.js
Line: 5
```

I tried changing .delegate to .on and the error doesn't appear anymore. Am i doing something wrong with .delegate ?

Comment: you are missing the selector.. `$( '.AddRow' ).delegate('SELECTOR', 'click', function() `

Comment: You didn't look at the documentation before asking, did you ?

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a parameter to `.delegate()`.  Probably you should use `.on()` anyway, though note that if you call it with just 2 parameters it's not going to be a delegated handler setup.

Answer (score 2):

See the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/).

`.delegate()` should be called on a container element. 
It takes three parameters: a selector to listen for events on, an event name, and a handler.